# Reorder svg elements in a force directed graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have a force directed graph with valued links. I put in a slider control that removes and adds links based on the value of the link (slide to 0.5 and only links of weight 0.5 and higher are displayed).

To do this I generally remove all the links and add them back based on the slider criteria. The problem I have though is that when I add the links back to the graph they appear on TOP of the nodes.

I want the nodes to be the highest "z-index", but I understand that SVG does not have a z-index. How can I reorder the elements so the nodes are back on top?  I've looked at the d3.select.order() and d3.select.sort() but I'm not quite sure how to use them to accomplish this reordering.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the display attribute to none instead of adding and removing nodes.

Alternatively, if you have a discrete number of weights, you could do it with CSS, like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- Hide all links with weights that we don't want -->
    .weight0,.weight2,.weight4,.weight6 {display:none}
  </style>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="weight0">
    <text y="20">weight 0</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="weight2">
    <text y="40">weight .2</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="weight4">
    <text y="60">weight .4</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="weight6">
    <text y="80">weight .6</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="weight8">
    <text y="100">weight .8</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#" class="weight10">
    <text y="120">weight 1</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even if the links are not displayed they still affect the force algorithm.

Comment: So you don't have influence on the algorithm?

Comment: Force algorithm is affected by the 'links' data - regardless if they are displayed or not. To effectively remove a link I need to remove it from the data as well. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout